# Limit of $\frac{\ln^{\alpha}(x)}{x}=0$

Tags: limits

I already proved that for $0<\alpha \in \mathbb R$: $\underset{x\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=0$ and also that $\underset{u\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln(u)}{u^{a}}=0$.
How would I use this information to prove that $\underset{x\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln^{\alpha}(x)}{x}=0$? l'Hopital doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a>0$, $$L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^a x}{x}= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^a}{e^{t}}=\lim_{t \to  \infty} t^a e^{-t}=0$$

Comment: Assuming I don't know that $\underset{t\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{e^{t}}=0$ - would I be somehow able to just use the two limits I already proved to prove it?

Comment: I figured that if I take $\alpha = 1/\alpha$ I can get to the answer without using it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\underset{u\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln(u)}{u^{a}}=0$ for $\alpha > 0$, so $\underset{u\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln(u)}{u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}=\underset{u\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln(u)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{u}}=0$.

$\underset{u\to\infty}{\lim}(\frac{\ln(u)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{u}}\cdot\overset{\alpha\,times}{\dots}\cdot\frac{\ln(u)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{u}})=0\cdot\dots\cdot0=\underset{u\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\ln^{\alpha}(u)}{u}$